# a mongodb shard shows strange slow behavior

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'm testing below aggregate

```
db.getCollection('token_transfer').explain("executionStats").aggregate([
    {$match: {
        $and: [{"contract_address":"0xTTTTTTTTTTT"}, {"timestamp": {$gte: ISODate("2019-12-13T00:45:05.000Z")}}]
    }},
    {$group: {
        _id: null,
        transfer_count: {$sum: 1},
        transfer_volume_sum: {$sum: "$value"},
    }}
])
```

indexes of the `token_transfer` collection is like below

```
{
    "contract_address" : 1.0,
    "value" : -1.0,
    "timestamp" : 1.0
},
{
    "tx_hash" : "hashed"
}
...
```

`token_transfer` collection has below fields

```
[contract_address, from, to, value, tx_hash, timestamp, ...]
```

shard key is like below

```
shard key: { "tx_hash" : "hashed" }
```

Key point is that it tooks `42706 executionTimeMillis` at only `shd2`.
The other shards show under `5000 executionTimeMillis`.

Why does slowness occur on certain shard which results in total query slow?

Below is my executionStats of aggregate.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "mergeType" : "mongos",
    "splitPipeline" : {
        "shardsPart" : [ 
            {
                "$match" : {
                    "$and" : [ 
                        {
                            "contract_address" : {
                                "$eq" : "0xTTTTTTTTTTT"
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "timestamp" : {
                                "$gte" : ISODate("2019-12-13T00:45:05.000Z")
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }, 
            {
                "$group" : {
                    "_id" : {
                        "$const" : null
                    },
                    "transfer_count" : {
                        "$sum" : {
                            "$const" : 1.0
                        }
                    },
                    "transfer_volume_sum" : {
                        "$sum" : "$value"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "mergerPart" : [ 
            {
                "$group" : {
                    "_id" : "$$ROOT._id",
                    "transfer_count" : {
                        "$sum" : "$$ROOT.transfer_count"
                    },
                    "transfer_volume_sum" : {
                        "$sum" : "$$ROOT.transfer_volume_sum"
                    },
                    "$doingMerge" : true
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "shards" : {
        "shd3" : {
            "host" : "x-db1:33333",
            "stages" : [ 
                {
                    "$cursor" : {
                        "query" : {
                            "$and" : [ 
                                {
                                    "contract_address" : "0xTTTTTTTTTTT"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "timestamp" : {
                                        "$gte" : ISODate("2019-12-13T00:45:05.000Z")
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "fields" : {
                            "value" : 1,
                            "_id" : 0
                        },
                        "queryPlanner" : {
                            "plannerVersion" : 1,
                            "namespace" : "test.token_transfer",
                            "indexFilterSet" : false,
                            "parsedQuery" : {
                                "$and" : [ 
                                    {
                                        "contract_address" : {
                                            "$eq" : "0xTTTTTTTTTTT"
                                        }
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                        "timestamp" : {
                                            "$gte" : ISODate("2019-12-13T00:45:05.000Z")
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "winningPlan" : {
                                "stage" : "PROJECTION",
                                "transformBy" : {
                                    "value" : 1,
                                    "_id" : 0
                                },
                                "inputStage" : {
                                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                    "keyPattern" : {
                                        "contract_address" : 1.0,
                                        "value" : -1.0,
                                        "timestamp" : 1.0
                                    },
                                    "indexName" : "contract_address_1_value_-1_timestamp_1",
                                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                        "contract_address" : [],
                                        "value" : [],
                                        "timestamp" : []
                                    },
                                    "isUnique" : false,
                                    "isSparse" : false,
                                    "isPartial" : false,
                                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                                    "direction" : "forward",
                                    "indexBounds" : {
                                        "contract_address" : [ 
                                            "[\"0xTTTTTTTTTTT\", \"0xTTTTTTTTTTT\"]"
                                        ],
                                        "value" : [ 
                                            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                        ],
                                        "timestamp" : [ 
                                            "[new Date(1576197905000), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "rejectedPlans" : []
                        },
                        "executionStats" : {
                            "executionSuccess" : true,
                            "nReturned" : 671,
                            "executionTimeMillis" : 1384,
                            "totalKeysExamined" : 1231507,
                            "totalDocsExamined" : 0,
                            "executionStages" : {
                                "stage" : "PROJECTION",
                                "nReturned" : 671,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 1370,
                                "works" : 1231507,
                                "advanced" : 671,
                                "needTime" : 1230835,
                                "needYield" : 0,
                                "saveState" : 9622,
                                "restoreState" : 9622,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                "transformBy" : {
                                    "value" : 1,
                                    "_id" : 0
                                },
                                "inputStage" : {
                                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                    "nReturned" : 671,
                                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 1340,
                                    "works" : 1231507,
                                    "advanced" : 671,
                                    "needTime" : 1230835,
                                    "needYield" : 0,
                                    "saveState" : 9622,
                                    "restoreState" : 9622,
                                    "isEOF" : 1,
                                    "invalidates" : 0,
                                    "keyPattern" : {
                                        "contract_address" : 1.0,
                                        "value" : -1.0,
                                        "timestamp" : 1.0
                                    },
                                    "indexName" : "contract_address_1_value_-1_timestamp_1",
                                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                        "contract_address" : [],
                                        "value" : [],
                                        "timestamp" : []
                                    },
                                    "isUnique" : false,
                                    "isSparse" : false,
                                    "isPartial" : false,
                                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                                    "direction" : "forward",
                                    "indexBounds" : {
                                        "contract_address" : [ 
                                            "[\"0xTTTTTTTTTTT\", \"0xTTTTTTTTTTT\"]"
                                        ],
                                        "value" : [ 
                                            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                        ],
                                        "timestamp" : [ 
                                            "[new Date(1576197905000), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "keysExamined" : 1231507,
                                    "seeks" : 1230836,
                                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                    "seenInvalidated" : 0
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "$group" : {
                        "_id" : {
                            "$const" : null
                        },
                        "transfer_count" : {
                            "$sum" : {
                                "$const" : 1.0
                            }
                        },
                        "transfer_volume_sum" : {
                            "$sum" : "$value"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "shd1" : {
            "host" : "x-db2:11111",
            "stages" : [ 
                {
                    "$cursor" : {
                        "query" : {
                            "$and" : [ 
                                {
                                    "contract_address" : "0xTTTTTTTTTTT"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "timestamp" : {
                                        "$gte" : ISODate("2019-12-13T00:45:05.000Z")
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "fields" : {
                            "value" : 1,
                            "_id" : 0
                        },
                        "queryPlanner" : {
                            "plannerVersion" : 1,
                            "namespace" : "test.token_transfer",
                            "indexFilterSet" : false,
                            "parsedQuery" : {
                                "$and" : [ 
                                    {
                                        "contract_address" : {
                                            "$eq" : "0xTTTTTTTTTTT"
                                        }
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                        "timestamp" : {
                                            "$gte" : ISODate("2019-12-13T00:45:05.000Z")
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "winningPlan" : {
                                "stage" : "PROJECTION",
                                "transformBy" : {
                                    "value" : 1,
                                    "_id" : 0
                                },
                                "inputStage" : {
                                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                    "keyPattern" : {
                                        "contract_address" : 1.0,
                                        "value" : -1.0,
                                        "timestamp" : 1.0
                                    },
                                    "indexName" : "contract_address_1_value_-1_timestamp_1",
                                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                        "contract_address" : [],
                                        "value" : [],
                                        "timestamp" : []
                                    },
                                    "isUnique" : false,
                                    "isSparse" : false,
                                    "isPartial" : false,
                                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                                    "direction" : "forward",
                                    "indexBounds" : {
                                        "contract_address" : [ 
                                            "[\"0xTTTTTTTTTTT\", \"0xTTTTTTTTTTT\"]"
                                        ],
                                        "value" : [ 
                                            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                        ],
                                        "timestamp" : [ 
                                            "[new Date(1576197905000), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "rejectedPlans" : []
                        },
                        "executionStats" : {
                            "executionSuccess" : true,
                            "nReturned" : 680,
                            "executionTimeMillis" : 4545,
                            "totalKeysExamined" : 1234518,
                            "totalDocsExamined" : 0,
                            "executionStages" : {
                                "stage" : "PROJECTION",
                                "nReturned" : 680,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 3685,
                                "works" : 1234518,
                                "advanced" : 680,
                                "needTime" : 1233837,
                                "needYield" : 0,
                                "saveState" : 9656,
                                "restoreState" : 9656,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                "transformBy" : {
                                    "value" : 1,
                                    "_id" : 0
                                },
                                "inputStage" : {
                                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                    "nReturned" : 680,
                                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 3685,
                                    "works" : 1234518,
                                    "advanced" : 680,
                                    "needTime" : 1233837,
                                    "needYield" : 0,
                                    "saveState" : 9656,
                                    "restoreState" : 9656,
                                    "isEOF" : 1,
                                    "invalidates" : 0,
                                    "keyPattern" : {
                                        "contract_address" : 1.0,
                                        "value" : -1.0,
                                        "timestamp" : 1.0
                                    },
                                    "indexName" : "contract_address_1_value_-1_timestamp_1",
                                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                        "contract_address" : [],
                                        "value" : [],
                                        "timestamp" : []
                                    },
                                    "isUnique" : false,
                                    "isSparse" : false,
                                    "isPartial" : false,
                                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                                    "direction" : "forward",
                                    "indexBounds" : {
                                        "contract_address" : [ 
                                            "[\"0xTTTTTTTTTTT\", \"0xTTTTTTTTTTT\"]"
                                        ],
                                        "value" : [ 
                                            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                        ],
                                        "timestamp" : [ 
                                            "[new Date(1576197905000), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "keysExamined" : 1234518,
                                    "seeks" : 1233838,
                                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                    "seenInvalidated" : 0
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "$group" : {
                        "_id" : {
                            "$const" : null
                        },
                        "transfer_count" : {
                            "$sum" : {
                                "$const" : 1.0
                            }
                        },
                        "transfer_volume_sum" : {
                            "$sum" : "$value"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "shd2" : {
            "host" : "x-db3:22222",
            "stages" : [ 
                {
                    "$cursor" : {
                        "query" : {
                            "$and" : [ 
                                {
                                    "contract_address" : "0xTTTTTTTTTTT"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "timestamp" : {
                                        "$gte" : ISODate("2019-12-13T00:45:05.000Z")
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "fields" : {
                            "value" : 1,
                            "_id" : 0
                        },
                        "queryPlanner" : {
                            "plannerVersion" : 1,
                            "namespace" : "test.token_transfer",
                            "indexFilterSet" : false,
                            "parsedQuery" : {
                                "$and" : [ 
                                    {
                                        "contract_address" : {
                                            "$eq" : "0xTTTTTTTTTTT"
                                        }
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                        "timestamp" : {
                                            "$gte" : ISODate("2019-12-13T00:45:05.000Z")
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "winningPlan" : {
                                "stage" : "PROJECTION",
                                "transformBy" : {
                                    "value" : 1,
                                    "_id" : 0
                                },
                                "inputStage" : {
                                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                    "keyPattern" : {
                                        "contract_address" : 1.0,
                                        "value" : -1.0,
                                        "timestamp" : 1.0
                                    },
                                    "indexName" : "contract_address_1_value_-1_timestamp_1",
                                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                        "contract_address" : [],
                                        "value" : [],
                                        "timestamp" : []
                                    },
                                    "isUnique" : false,
                                    "isSparse" : false,
                                    "isPartial" : false,
                                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                                    "direction" : "forward",
                                    "indexBounds" : {
                                        "contract_address" : [ 
                                            "[\"0xTTTTTTTTTTT\", \"0xTTTTTTTTTTT\"]"
                                        ],
                                        "value" : [ 
                                            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                        ],
                                        "timestamp" : [ 
                                            "[new Date(1576197905000), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "rejectedPlans" : []
                        },
                        "executionStats" : {
                            "executionSuccess" : true,
                            "nReturned" : 720,
                            "executionTimeMillis" : 42706,
                            "totalKeysExamined" : 1181569,
                            "totalDocsExamined" : 0,
                            "executionStages" : {
                                "stage" : "PROJECTION",
                                "nReturned" : 720,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 4284,
                                "works" : 1181569,
                                "advanced" : 720,
                                "needTime" : 1180848,
                                "needYield" : 0,
                                "saveState" : 9249,
                                "restoreState" : 9249,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                "transformBy" : {
                                    "value" : 1,
                                    "_id" : 0
                                },
                                "inputStage" : {
                                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                    "nReturned" : 720,
                                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 4244,
                                    "works" : 1181569,
                                    "advanced" : 720,
                                    "needTime" : 1180848,
                                    "needYield" : 0,
                                    "saveState" : 9249,
                                    "restoreState" : 9249,
                                    "isEOF" : 1,
                                    "invalidates" : 0,
                                    "keyPattern" : {
                                        "contract_address" : 1.0,
                                        "value" : -1.0,
                                        "timestamp" : 1.0
                                    },
                                    "indexName" : "contract_address_1_value_-1_timestamp_1",
                                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                        "contract_address" : [],
                                        "value" : [],
                                        "timestamp" : []
                                    },
                                    "isUnique" : false,
                                    "isSparse" : false,
                                    "isPartial" : false,
                                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                                    "direction" : "forward",
                                    "indexBounds" : {
                                        "contract_address" : [ 
                                            "[\"0xTTTTTTTTTTT\", \"0xTTTTTTTTTTT\"]"
                                        ],
                                        "value" : [ 
                                            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                        ],
                                        "timestamp" : [ 
                                            "[new Date(1576197905000), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "keysExamined" : 1181569,
                                    "seeks" : 1180849,
                                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                    "seenInvalidated" : 0
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "$group" : {
                        "_id" : {
                            "$const" : null
                        },
                        "transfer_count" : {
                            "$sum" : {
                                "$const" : 1.0
                            }
                        },
                        "transfer_volume_sum" : {
                            "$sum" : "$value"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "ok" : 1.0,
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1576201630, 116),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : { "$binary" : "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "$type" : "00" },
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1576201630, 115)
}
```

Comment: What is the shard key field(s)?

Comment: @prasad_ `tx_hash` is shard key.
I updated it on ask body, too.

Comment: ` shd2`servers are low on resources (CPU or RAM), perhaps? May be there is more data on it to examine? There is some other load on the shd2 server? Is the issue consistent  all the time?